# custom sorting values of dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting

I want to custom sort my dataframe. This is sample dataframe which has structure like mine:

```
data = {'name':['name1','name1','name1','name2','name2','name2','name3','name3','name3'],
        'col1':[19, 38, 25, 10, 39, 28, 25, 20, 23],
        'col2':[29, 28, 25, 20, 19, 18, 15, 10, 13],
        'col3':[9, 8, 5, 0, 9, 8, 5, 0, 3]} 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['2020-12-31',
                                '2021-01-31',
                                '2021-02-28', 
                                '2020-12-31',
                                '2021-01-31',
                                '2021-02-28', 
                                '2020-12-31', 
                                '2021-01-31',
                                '2021-02-28'])
df.index.name = 'date'
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
print(df)
```

The output:

```
         date   name  col1  col2  col3
0  2020-12-31  name1    19    29     9
1  2021-01-31  name1    38    28     8
2  2021-02-28  name1    25    25     5
3  2020-12-31  name2    10    20     0
4  2021-01-31  name2    39    19     9
5  2021-02-28  name2    28    18     8
6  2020-12-31  name3    25    15     5
7  2021-01-31  name3    20    10     0
8  2021-02-28  name3    23    13     3
```

Firstly, I sorted date column in this way:

```
df.sort_values(by=['date'], inplace = True)
```

The second output:

```
         date   name  col1  col2  col3
0  2020-12-31  name1    19    29     9
3  2020-12-31  name2    10    20     0
6  2020-12-31  name3    25    15     5
1  2021-01-31  name1    38    28     8
4  2021-01-31  name2    39    19     9
7  2021-01-31  name3    20    10     0
2  2021-02-28  name1    25    25     5
5  2021-02-28  name2    28    18     8
8  2021-02-28  name3    23    13     3
```

Now, I want to sort name column, I tried categorical sorting, but I can't achieve my desired output. So I want to sort the name column without sorting the date column. How can I get it?

Expected output:

```
         date   name  col1  col2  col3
0  2020-12-31  name3    25    15     5
3  2020-12-31  name2    10    20     0
6  2020-12-31  name1    19    29     9
1  2021-01-31  name3    20    10     0
4  2021-01-31  name2    39    19     9
7  2021-01-31  name1    38    28     8
2  2021-02-28  name3    23    13     3
5  2021-02-28  name2    28    18     8
8  2021-02-28  name1    25    25     5
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to sort groups of three rows:

```
groups = df.reset_index().loc[:,"date":].groupby(lambda x: int(x/3))
df[:] = groups.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values("name", ascending = False)).values

print(df)
#         date   name  col1  col2  col3
#0  2020-12-31  name3    25    15     5
#3  2020-12-31  name2    10    20     0
#6  2020-12-31  name1    19    29     9
#1  2021-01-31  name3    20    10     0
#4  2021-01-31  name2    39    19     9
#7  2021-01-31  name1    38    28     8
#2  2021-02-28  name3    23    13     3
#5  2021-02-28  name2    28    18     8
#8  2021-02-28  name1    25    25     5
```

Comment: I got this error: "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray"